# Closure property of regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

I am trying to prove the closure property of regular language with a function $f(w)$ over alphabet $\Sigma$ for any string $w \in \Sigma^*$.

$f(w) =$ string obtained by taking symbols of $w$ at even position (ex. $f(aabbaa) = aba$).

I define
$$
f(L) = \{ f(w) \mid  w ∈ L \}
$$

I am trying to prove that for any regular language $L$, $f(L)$ is also regular.

I am a little confused on how to prove this. What I am thinking  is to create a NFA that would skip every other string through empty string progression but not sure how to define this mathematically. Any help is appreciated

Comment: This very similar question may be useful:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769532/can-you-draw-the-e-nfa-from-the-following-definition/769588#769588

Answer (score 1):

Use closure properties of regular languages. Define the new alphabet $\Gamma = \Sigma \cup \{\chi\}$, where $\chi \notin \Sigma$. The languages $L_a = \{a, \chi\}$ are finite, thus regular. So the substitution defined by $s(a) = L_a$ applied to your language $L$ gives a regular language. Intersecting that with $((a \mid b \mid \ldots) \chi)^*$ gives a regular language. Use the homomorphism:
$$h(x) = \begin{cases}
           x & x \ne \chi \\
           \epsilon & x = \chi
         \end{cases}$$
The result of the homomorphism is what you want:

$$f(L) = h(s(L) \cap ((a \mid b \mid \ldots) \chi)^*)$$

Each step preserves regularity, thus the result is regular.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "skip every other *string*", however, I assume that you want to build an NFA with $\epsilon$-transitions.

You can generate a new NFA with $\epsilon$-transitions accepting your modified language as follows. For each state $q$ of your NFA, create *two* states in your modified NFA: one corresponding to "original" $q$, and one "phantom state"  $q^\prime$. For each transition labelled by symbol $s$ from state $a$ to $b$ in the original NFA, generate an $\epsilon$-transition from $a$ to $b^\prime$ and a transition labelled by $s$ from $a^\prime$ to $b$.

This results in a bipartite graph, and your NFA now jumps to the "phantom"-half of the graph in every second step, essentially skipping all the characters that were on the odd positions in the original string. Now, one should be able to verify that this NFA accepts the new modified language by the obvious induction.

Comment: I made a typing error what I meant was skip every character. I think I get the concept. I am now trying to define a 5 tuple (with  set of states, input symbols, transition function, start state, set of accepting states) for the modified NFA (which I believe is the NFA accepting characters at even position). If I understand correctly, what is different between the original nfa and the modified is the transition function?

Comment: There are many different ways to achieve the same effect. In *my particular proposal* above, almost every part of the quintuple (everything except $\Sigma$) is different. There are twice as many states: I would use $Q\coprod Q$ instead of $Q$. The transition function has completely different domain and codomain, and adds bunch of additional $\epsilon$-edges. The start state is "the image of the original start state under the canonical embedding". The accepting states are images of the original accepting states under the two injections. It's all more or less "canonical" though.

Comment: I tried your construction on $\Delta = \{ (a, s, b), (b, t, c), (c, u, d)\}$, $q_0 = a$, $F = \{ d \}$ and the resulting NFA only seems to skip $s$.

Comment: Your $Q=\{a,b,c,d\}$, there are three edges $\Delta$, and the only accepted word is "stu", is this correct? My construction would yield NFA with states $\{a,a',b,b',c,c',d,d'\}$, transitions $\{(a,\epsilon,b'), (a',s,b), (b,\epsilon,c'),(b',t,c),(c,\epsilon,d'),(c',u,d)\}$, $q_0=a$, $F=\{d,d'\}$. There is only one sequence of transitions that lead to $F$, namely: $a \to^\epsilon b' \to ^ t c \to^\epsilon d'$, thus it accepts only the word "t". This is the language $f(L)$. Please correct me if I misunderstood your notation somehow.

Comment: I understand this transition. Thank you. but if I were to generalize how do I form a transition function for "one corresponding to "original" qq, and one "phantom state" q′"

Comment: As I said above: if there is an edge $(A, s, B)$ in the original automaton, add two edges $(A,\epsilon,B^\prime)$ and $(A^\prime,s,B)$ to the new automaton. This specifies a ternary *relation* on $(Q\coprod Q)\times(\Sigma \cup \{\epsilon\})\times(Q\coprod Q)$. If you really want to, you can re-interpret this relation as a "non-deterministic transition function" $\delta: (Q\coprod Q)\times(\Sigma \cup\{\epsilon\}) \to \mathfrak{P}(Q\coprod Q)$.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to prove the closure property of regular language with a
>   function f(w) over alphabet Σ for any string w ∈ Σ∗.

I expect that closure property to hold only for certain mappings. Wikipedia lists string homomorphisms (replace characters with words), inverse string homomorphisms (seem to replace words with characters) and finite state transducers (seem to replace words with words).

> $f(w)$ = string obtained by taking symbols of $w$ at even position,
>   ex. $f(aabbaa) = aba$.

This kind of function acts on position, IMHO in general it can not be implemented by a finite list of input strings to be replaced with some output strings.

> I define
>
> ```
> f(w) = { f(w): w ∈ L }
> ```

Do you mean $f(L)$?

Comment: Yes, it should be $f(L)$. I just edited the question.